# Why do inputs and selects use different box models?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, w3c, css

It appears (at least in IE 8 and Firefox 3) that for <input> elements the width refers to the content, but for <select> elements the width refers to the content + borders.  I am explicitly specifying the width in the CSS style.

What's the deal?  I would have thought that both are inline replaced elements and would behave identically.  Is this behavior consistent with W3C standards?  Does it work this way in all major browsers?

Answer (score 2):

Select sizing differs from inputs sizing because of different box-sizing. Input has box-sizing set to "content-box" while select has box-sizing set to 'border-box'. In example below input will be wider than select:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="a" style="width:100px; border:5px solid red; padding: 10px;" />
<select name="b" style="width:100px; border:5px solid red; padding: 10px;" /><option value="b">b</option></select>
```

it is because full width for input will be width+padding(left+right)+border(left+right) and for select full width will be just width (but you know that). To make both element behave same way you have to change box-sizing model. In example below input and select will have exactly the same width*:

```
<input type="text" name="a" value="a" style="width:100px; border:5px solid red; padding: 10px;" />
<select name="b" style="box-sizing: content-box; width:100px; border:5px solid red; padding: 10px;" /><option value="b">b</option></select>
```

*use -moz-box-sizing for firefox

As i know this behavior is consistent in all modern browsers (including iE6) but i dont know why it works this way. Don't know any W3 spec where is this particular behavior described. There is [note suggesting default styling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) but it covers only simple attributes - that's why reseting default css is so popular.

Answer (score 2):

I used this on CSS an work perfectly:

```
input, select
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

With this you force the behavior of inputs and select to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers were around before the W3C so they defined their own rendering rules. Browsers won't ever be consistent ( in the near future ) in regards to form control styling because default browser styles are inconsistent and form controls are rendered by different OSes.

This site lists default browser styles: http://www.iecss.com/ ( The styling of inputs is inconsistent )

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But I'm not really asking about default styles, but rather about why when I explicitly set a style (e.g. `width: 150px`) this is treated differently on <input>'s vs. <select>'s.

Comment: That site only lists styling for IE and is far out of date for all the others listed at the end of the page. If one wants to see the styling, they can always use the built in developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a best practice to "reset" the base styles of all controls and other common elements (like html, body, etc.) to a common ground minimum. While not guaranteed to produce perfectly matching controls in all browsers, it gets you much closer. There are a wide variety of premade reset CSS that you can simply use off of the internet. One of the most common is YUI's reset css:

- [YUI Reset CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/)

Once resetting your CSS, to resolve the width discrepancy, you would simply need to set a standard default border and padding for your input controls that properly accommodates your sites style.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is less about the default styles than why a style that I set is treated differently.  I mean, I know I can set the width and borders to whatever I want, say `width:150px; border-width:2px` but why does this produce an element with 150px internal width for <input>'s and 150px external width (border included) for <select>'s?  And is that strange fact true in all major browsers?

Comment: @Tim: I do see the problem (I guess I misunderstood the original intent of your question before). As for "why"...I doubt anyone really knows. I do know that in IE8 and FF3, they make use of the underlying system controls to render `input` and `select`. Some other browsers do fully custom rendering of such controls. Depending on the OS, it is entirely possible that any browsers that are OS-dependent for rendering input and select controls will have differing behavior. It is an annoying quirk, and one that really shouldn't exist in the modern age of pixel-perfect layout...but...what can you do?

Comment: Just set the values to what you want. In most cases you do anyway. A reset, that so many people want to throw at every problem, is not often needed and hardly a best practice. Like the ubiquitous jQuery solves all issues no matter how minor.